How to prove the classical definition of addition map for additive ordinary categories is commutative and associative up to coherent homotopy?
Could somebody please help me with this?
We know if $C$ is an ordinary additive category, then the addition of maps $f,g:x \rightarrow y$ coincides with the composition
$$x \xrightarrow{\bigtriangleup} x \oplus x \xrightarrow{(f,g)} y \oplus y \xrightarrow{\bigtriangledown} y,$$
which first and last maps are diagonal and codiagonal maps respectively. This map defines an abelian group structure on $\text{Hom}_C(x,y)$.
Now, here is my main question! if $C$ is an additive $\infty$-category, how can we show this operation (on $\text{Map}_C(x,y)$) is commutative and associative up to coherent homotopy? How can we show it is commutative and associative up to just homotopy?

Do you know how to prove it in a 1-category? If not, meditate on this diagram (where $\sigma$ is the swap map).

LaTeX note: \oplus is a binary operations, while \bigoplus is basically a unary operation.

A reference for this is Remark C.1.5.3 of Lurie's Spectral Algebraic Geometry. The remark only makes use of material from Higher Algebra.

@NaïmFavier Thank you, yes I do. How about associativity? I mean what map should we use instead of the swap map to prove the associativity law?

@BrianShin Thank you! I am looking for a very straight proof, like the ordinary case. do you know other resources that have different proof other than the mentioned one in Lurie's?

You use the obvious associativity $(x \oplus x) \oplus x \simeq x \oplus (x \oplus x)$, as in this diagram.

@A.karimi Are you sure that you really are looking for "commutative and associative up to coherent homotopy"? It is somewhat of a challenge to even define what that means, let alone actually demonstrate a particular object satisfies it, so I doubt that you are going to find a proof as simple as the 1-categorical case.

@ConnorMalin Thank you! Yes, I think you are right, it is not very easy to find such proof. But, I think at least knowing the fact that mapping spaces in additive infinity categories can be regarded as grouplikes commutative monoid objects in N(Kan) (infinity category of spaces), we can somehow conclude that the defined addition map in the ordinary case will take care of coherency.
